# PHP version in phpinfo() does not match version active on ubuntu server

Tags: php, ubuntu

I updated my php version to 8.1, and inside `/etc/php` I have two directories: 8.0 and 8.1 - I'm not sure if and how I should get rid of 8.0?

Yet mi biggest concern is, that `sudo php -v` does return as expected:

```
PHP 8.1.2 (cli) (built: Jan 24 2022 10:42:33) (NTS)
```

However if I use `phpinfo()` in my script, it returns `PHP Version 8.0.15`. What am I missing? What should I do in order to use current PHP version in my scripts?

EDIT:

`sudo a2dismod php8.0` gives `Module php8.0 already disabled`, while `sudo a2enmod php8.1` returns:

```
Considering dependency mpm_prefork for php8.1:
Considering conflict mpm_event for mpm_prefork:
Considering conflict mpm_worker for mpm_prefork:
Module mpm_prefork already enabled
Considering conflict php5 for php8.1:
Module php8.1 already enabled
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to reconfigure your Apache server to use the PHP version you want. Check the loaded Apache configuration files, e.g `httpd.conf` or your OS specific one.

You need to tell **Apache** web server to use the PHP 8.1 version you installed.

If you use *Debian* or similar OS you can disable the old PHP module and enable the new PHP module using the following command.

```sh
sudo a2dismod php8.0
sudo a2enmod php8.1
```

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu server 20.10. AFAIR configuration file should be in my case `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` - yet I don't know what exactly should I change there? As for dismod/enmod - please check edit in main post where I posted effects.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know why this issue is not addressed properly.

I am working with different PHP projects having different PHP versions on my ubuntu system [ppa:ondrej/php](https://launchpad.net/%7Eondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php/).

CLI has its own configuration file and Apache2 has its own configuration file.
[image]

The CLI and FPM configuration files are different hence CLI and Apache PHP versions are different.

> service --status-all

The above command will list all services' status in Linux  and we can see the result something like this

```
 [ + ]  php7.4-fpm
 [ + ]  php8.0-fpm
 [ + ]  php8.1-fpm
 [ + ]  php8.2-fpm
```

This is the problem - running multiple PHP FPM.

To resolve this - e.g. to keep PHP 8.1 Running
in Apache2

```
// disable unnecessary fpm
sudo a2disconf php7.4-fpm;  
sudo a2disconf php8.0-fpm;  
sudo a2disconf php8.2-fpm;  
// enable expected fpm 
sudo a2enconf php8.1-fpm;
```

That's it. Now in CLI `php -v` will return php8.1 and Apache `phpinfo();` will also show php8.1

I am using some bash script to make life easy.

```
php74(){
sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php7.4; 
sudo a2dismod php8.0; 
sudo a2dismod php8.1;
sudo a2dismod php8.2;
sudo a2disconf php8.0-fpm; 
sudo a2disconf php8.1-fpm;
sudo a2disconf php8.2-fpm; 
sudo a2enmod php7.4; 
sudo a2enconf php7.4-fpm;
systemctl restart apache2
}

php80(){
sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php8.0; 
sudo a2dismod php7.4; 
sudo a2dismod php8.1;
sudo a2dismod php8.2;
sudo a2disconf php7.4-fpm; 
sudo a2disconf php8.1-fpm;
sudo a2disconf php8.2-fpm; 
sudo a2enmod php8.0;
sudo a2enconf php8.0-fpm;
systemctl restart apache2
}

php81(){
sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php8.1; 
sudo a2dismod php7.4; 
sudo a2dismod php8.0;
sudo a2dismod php8.2;
sudo a2disconf php7.4-fpm; 
sudo a2disconf php8.0-fpm;
sudo a2disconf php8.2-fpm; 
sudo a2enmod php8.1;
sudo a2enconf php8.1-fpm;
systemctl restart apache2
}

php82(){
sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php8.2; 
sudo a2dismod php7.4; 
sudo a2dismod php8.0; 
sudo a2dismod php8.1;
sudo a2disconf php7.4-fpm; 
sudo a2disconf php8.0-fpm;
sudo a2disconf php8.1-fpm; 
sudo a2enmod php8.2;
sudo a2enconf php8.2-fpm;
systemctl restart apache2
}
```

In the terminal, I am running `php74`, `php80`, `php81`, and `php82` commands to set the PHP version in both CLI and Apache2.

Comment: Thanks Ravi I have use below command and its working fine
sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php8.1; 
sudo a2dismod php7.4; 
sudo a2dismod php8.0;
sudo a2dismod php8.2;
sudo a2disconf php7.4-fpm; 
sudo a2disconf php8.0-fpm;
sudo a2disconf php8.2-fpm; 
sudo a2enmod php8.1;
sudo a2enconf php8.1-fpm;
systemctl restart apache2

Answer (score 0):

As documented in [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1314777/why-does-apache-need-stop-and-start-rather-than-restart-for-new-php-version-to#:%7E:text=Whenever%20we%20get%20a%20package,the%20correct%20version%20of%20PHP.) answer if you stop and restart apache it will load the latest PHP version from disk.

Comment: It would make sense, yet I restarted apache many times, even rebooted whole server, and still nothing. I have no idea where to look for the reason.

Comment: Do not provide link-only answers. Even if it does provide an answer to OP's question, links change.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo a2dismod php8.0
sudo a2dismod php8.1
sudo a2dismod mpm_prefork php8.0
sudo a2dismod mpm_event php8.0
sudo a2dismod mpm_worker php8.0
sudo a2enmod php8.1
//I know, it still displays notifications about the conflicts
sudo systemctl restart apache2
php -v
```

Comment: `php -v` does return correct value, but `phpinfo()` raport does output `8.0.15`. Please take a look ghow Your commands did look like (this is text host with my server output): https://traff.co/19v8BcOl